# MissingManifestResourceException for EmbeddedResouce in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, exception, embedded-resource

I write Silverlight games using XNA-based Silverlight engines. I have a previous game where I have files (MP3s and text files) with `Build Action` set to `Embedded Resource`, and no `*.resx` file to be seen in my solution.

The game runs fine; you can see the production version [here](http://deengames.com/play/valence).

On the other hand, my current project doesn't allow this. When I try to make files `Embedded Resource`s, I get a *MissingManifestResourceException* thrown in my constructor of the main `UserControl` instance that starts my app. The error message is:

> Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "DeenGames.Colosseum.Content.Audio.2.mp3.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "DeenGames.Colosseum" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.

I'm very, very, *very* perplexed. Setting any item's `Build Action` to `Embedded Resource`, whether MP3, text, or image, causes this exception.

How the heck do I fix (or debug) this? I'm 99% sure I do *not* need a `.resx` file, because my previous projects don't have one.

There's [this lovely MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296240%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) which assures the world that:

> In particular, Silverlight embedded resources must always use the
>   Resource build action, and not the Embedded Resource build action,
>   which uses a format that Silverlight cannot recognize.

But there's a well-known solution using `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames()`. In my case, it doesn't show me the resource if it's just a `Resource`; if it's an `Embedded Resource`, I can see the file name with dot-delimited namespace (as expected).

Download and see for yourself a very simple working example [here](http://deengames.com/wp-content/uploads/downloads/2011/09/qadar.zip). It has two embedded files (.2dg and .map) and compiles/runs without any exceptions OR resx file.

You can also download a broken example [here](http://deengames.com/wp-content/uploads/downloads/2011/09/colosseum.zip). Replace FlatRedBall.dll with RadiantWrench.dll and watch the working example break. (Use `ScreenController.ShowScreen` and remove all FRB-referenced code.)

Comment: Answer updated below. I believe it's a simple as using the same 3rd party tool to read these files in the new project as you did in the first project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Embedded Resource* is a WinForms technology that is depreciated in the Silverlight runtime. Instead, a build action of *Resource* or *Content* should be used instead.

When you set an item to *Embedded Resource*, Silverlight expects this to be a .resx file because this is what happens inside the .csproj or .vbproj file when you create a .resx and add resources to it (the file is marked as *Embedded Resource* for MSBuild and its resources are simply a `None` inside of an `<ItemGroup/>` that are discovered by the ResXGenerator at runtime based off the relative URI folder of "Resources"). If it isn't, it removes it or sets it as *Content*. You can examine **Microsoft.Silverlight.Common.targets** (usually in your C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Silverlight\v4.0 folder) to see how it changes items marked as *Embedded Resource* - setting to content, setting to none or setting to a .resx file.

If you're looking to just query what resources you have in the project, you could try this somewhat cumbersome approach: [Enumerating embedded resources](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/alex_golesh/archive/2009/11/13/silverlight-tip-enumerating-embedded-resources.aspx)

---

UPDATE: In looking at your project, this is not really using an Embedded Resource the way WinForms uses this Build Action type or even .resx, per say. It uses a function from the *ToolsSilverlight.dll* called `EmbeddedResourceFileReader.ReadFile`. The code for that is:

```
    private static string ReadFile(string fileName, Assembly currentAssembly)
    {
        string text = EmbeddedResourceHelper.CheckAndSanitizePath(fileName);
        string result = "";
        using (Stream manifestResourceStream = currentAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(text))
        {
            if (manifestResourceStream == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Couldn't open " + fileName + ". Make sure the file exists in that directory, and has Build Action set to Embedded Resource.");
            }
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(manifestResourceStream))
            {
                result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Your .csproject file lists your files as:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Content\Qadar.2dg" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Content\Maps\main.map" />
    <None Include="Properties\AppManifest.xml" />
</ItemGroup>
```

All this does is embed, as mentioned with the **Microsoft.Silverlight.Common.targets** above, your files as common Resources (at a top level, not with the list of other actual resouces) and finds a way to read them. You can decompile your DLL with ILSpy to exam that these are indeed now common Resources under the Resources folder.

So how can you do this in your new project? Replicate the exact method you did in your first one - add ToolsSilverlight.dll, list your items as Embedded Resource, and call them using `EmbeddedResourceFileReader.ReadFile`. You may also want to ensure your .csproj file `<ItemGroup/>` structure is similar to original one. Not sure if `<None Include="Properties\AppManifest.xml"/>` is needed by `EmbeddedResourceFileReader`, but it may be.

Comment: Sorry, gotta -1 you as well then. The answer is what you're going to get - *in Windows Phone, you can only use Resource or Content*. You're not going to find a different answer.

Comment: Ugh, you're right. Not sure where I got "Windows Phone" in my head. I've changed the answer above and removed the -1.

Comment: You may want to post a part of the source code that is believed to work with items marked as Embedded Resource (redacting non-relevant parts, of course) to DropBox or some other location.

Comment: Okay, I've removed my -1 and uploaded a sample project.

Comment: Ah, it's not that simple. EmbeddedResource* classes are actually mine; they use the usual Assembly.GetManifestBlah methods mentioned in my question. As far as I can see, the two csproj files are identical. I'm not sure why one works and the other doesn't. Besides which, I can't even reach called to any classes -- my application immediately throws the runtime exception mentioned in my question.

Comment: Can you post the project that doesn't work and I'll take a look at that?

Comment: okay, I've uploaded it and updated my question. You can even break the working example by replacing the FlatRedBall.dll with RadiantWrench.dll. The API is almost equivalent, just change `ScreenManager.Start(...)` to `ScreenController.Show(...)` and you should be ready to go.

Comment: In walking up the code, it appears the issue lies with `SilverArcade.SilverSprite.Manifest.Discovery.GetResourcesInternal()` and it's inability to resolve the files. I haven't compared that against the original one. If it is the same, it could be a timing issue.

Comment: I know this is getting very complicated. How do you suggest I solve this problem? I can't use normal resources because resource refer to each other, and I don't necessarily know at runtime which resource I'm going to need.

Comment: In looking at the `GetResourcesInternal` from the package that works, it appears to be different, especially the beginning on how it gets `Parts`. I guess the first thing I'd try is to replicate that in the new code base. Other than that, you may be running out of options.

Comment: I don't have control over SilverSprite and FlatRedBall. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Can you write your own .dlls based on those (legally, I mean)? The source code of those dlls and others can be viewed in ILSpy. SilverSprite looks like it may come from http://silversprite.codeplex.com/, in which case it is open source. But the SilverSprite dll used in the first project is different from the one in the second project, like the `GetResourcesInternal` routine, so could you just use the one from the first project?

Comment: I already emailed the author of SilverSprite and referred him to this thread. I'm not sure if he will even read it. I guess I can try fixing it myself :( the older DLL won't work (from the first project), it's not compatible with my library.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I think you've done more than enough to deserve the 50 rep. Enjoy.