# Returning Resources Based on a Key

Tags: c#, resources, embedded-resource

Based on my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488282/missingmanifestresourceexception-for-embeddedresouce-in-silverlight), it looks like emedded resources are not going to work in my project. So plan #2 is to use regular resources via a resx file.

The core of my question is: **is it possible to write a function that will take a string key, and return that resource?** I tried this with reflection, but I couldn't get it to work.

Here's a sample of how I would like it to work. Let's say I have a `Resources.resx` file, which has two file resources: `MainMap` and `OverWorld`. I would like to write the function that works like:

```
string mainMapContent = getFromResources("MainMap"); // => returns Resources.MainMap
string overWorldCOntent = getFromResoures("OverWOrld"); // => returns Resources.OverWorld
```

I tried using reflection to create an instance of the `Resources` class, but bailed out when I realized the constructor is internal and there's no empty constructor I can use.

Is there a way to write this `getFromResources` function? I can't figure it out.

**Note:** I will probably put this into a library if I can do it; it needs to work with the Silverlight runtime, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strongly typed resource class that is generated through code-generation is based on the untyped ResourceManager class. You should be able to use [ResourceManager.GetObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/963f81yd.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, it worked. The only trick was the constructor, which takes the resource-holder's type. Easy breezy after that.